# Difference in the meaning between "Life has changed for all of us" and "Life has changed all of us"?

Tags: for

What is the difference in the meaning between "Life has changed for all of us" and "Life has changed all of us" ?

Does "Life has changed for all of us" mean "Because of all of us, Life has changed" ?
Does "Life has changed all of us" mean "Because of Life, all of us are changed" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Life has changed for all of us" means "Our life has changed."

"Life has changed all of us" means, as you said, "Because of life, we are different from what we used to be."

Comment: Is it possible to use the word for possessive by using for?

For example,  Can I change "your ability is truly amazing"  as " ability is truly amazing for you"?  Can I change a sentence like this one like this?  It's really a mess. Could you please give me some more examples?

Comment: No, you have to say "Your ability is truly amazing." With "life" it's different -- like "death", in your sentences further above it has a meaning independent of us, human beings. Notice that we say "Life has changed (for) all of us" but "Circumstances have changed / The current situation has changed our lives."

Comment: It's really a mess. Could you please explain the differences with some easy examples?

Comment: Can I change "Our dog barks at people" as "Dog barks at people for us" ? Can I change "When we carry heavy loads, our legs often break" as "When we carry heavy loads, legs often break for us" ?

Comment: No, you definitely can't. As I told you, "life" is a special case.